# Transform Matrix into component pieces

Tags: math, matrix, transform, inverse

Given an affine 2D transform matrix such as:

```
[a  b  tx]
[c  d  ty]
[0  0  1 ]
```

- For a clockwise rotation about the origin, `a` is transformed by `cos (θ)` and `b` is transformed by `sin (θ)`
- For a scaleX of scaleFactor sx, `a` is transformed by `sx`
- For a shear parallel to the x axis, `x' = x + ky` `b` is transformed by `k`

---

In my example, `a` was transformed twice, by the rotation and the scale-x, `b` was transformed twice, once by the rotation, once by the shear.

Rotation is no longer just `arcsin(b)`

ScaleX is no longer just `1 / a`

ShearX is no longer just `x - ky`

---

How can I get the values of `rotation`, `shearX`, and `scaleX` back from that matrix?

Comment: Homework?  If yes, please tag it as such.

Comment: Not homework. Just curiosity. Check out my profile for evidence that I've finished school =]

Comment: No evidence that I can see, but that's okay.  I'll take your word for it.

Comment: I'm 21 and employed as a software developer.

Comment: "On the Internet, no one can tell that you're a dog." - 21 is prime university age, and lots of students have part time jobs.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said 'evidence', not proof. I did kinda forget about uni though, that was 2 years ago! =p

Comment: I am not sure whether I fully understand what you mean, but I will attempt answer anyhow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So rotation matrix (full) will be ( I leave out the boring part)

```
R=
a=cos(θ)  c=sin(θ)
b=-sin(θ) d=cos(θ)
```

while scale and shear matrix will be (again, leaving out the boring part)

```
S=
a=s  b=k 
c=0  d=1
```

Now applying FIRST rotation (R), THEN scale and shear (S) will just be multiplying the matrices, which gives resulting matrix

```
S times R
a=s cos(θ) - k sin(θ)   b=s sin(θ)+k cos(θ)
c=-sin(theta)    d=cos(theta)
```

If you would want to get back θ, s and k from that, you can determine θ =arcsin(-c). You know sin(θ) and cos(θ), so you can solve two linear equations (a=s cos(θ) - k sin(θ)   b=s sin(θ)+k cos(θ)) with two unknowns to find s and k.

Comment: Simultaneous equations! Ingenious!